# Apache Hadoop and Eclipse integration

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I am currently trying to integrate Hadoop with Eclipse. I followed the instructions from  [here](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2012/10/debugging-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in.html). However, when I attempt to run my Eclipse project I get the following output:

```
13/04/01 14:55:11 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/04/01 14:55:11 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
13/04/01 14:55:11 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/04/01 14:55:11 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/04/01 14:55:11 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
13/04/01 14:55:11 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
13/04/01 14:55:11 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@6ea920ad
13/04/01 14:55:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/04/01 14:55:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
13/04/01 14:55:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
13/04/01 14:55:11 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0001
java.lang.ClassCastException: interface javax.xml.soap.Text
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3046)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getOutputKeyComparator(JobConf.java:774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.<init>(MapTask.java:959)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
13/04/01 14:55:12 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/04/01 14:55:12 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
13/04/01 14:55:12 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
false
```

My machine is a Linux Ubuntu 12.04 with Apache Hadoop version 1.04, Oracle Java v1.7 and Eclipse 3.7.2.
Why am I getting this output? If I am doing something wrong, can anyone direct me to a tested method in order to make it work?

Thank you

P.S.: I am writing a wiki at the moment for undergraduate students that want to start "playing" with big-data. Hence, a large group of people are going to benefit from a good answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please switch to the new API, i.e the "mapreduce" and not "mapred". Also, it makes more sense since you are planning to write a wiki for students. They should be up to date. Right?And if you need something on how to setup eclipse to write MapReduce programs, you might find this [link](http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-run-mapreduce-programs-using.html#.UVwdZzWH6IQ) useful.

Comment: Ok, I will try your recommendations. Thank you for your help.